# Compact Riley riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My prefix is evil, in 5 letters.
>
> My infix is an abbreviation, in 3 letters.
>
> My suffix is in past tense, in 3 letters.
>
> Together, they have no intersection.

What am I?

Comment: While this riddle is pleasingly compact, I fear the infix and suffix in particular are so vague and general that you're going to receive a LOT of 'incorrect' answers which fit the riddle as it stands!

Comment: @Stiv Made the riddle more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **demonstrate**

Explanation:

*My prefix is evil.*

> **demon** - a creature from the abyss

*My infix is an abbreviation.*

> **str** is an abbreviation for street

*My suffix is in past tense.*

> **ate** is the past tense form of eat

*Together, they have no intersection.*

> All the affixes put together with no intersection yields **demonstrate**.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE and congratulations on your first answer! Though I intended rot13("fgevat" sbe "fge.")

Comment: @DannyuNDos rot13(uzz bs pbhefr, naq zr n cebtenzzre gbb!)

Answer (score 5):

My guess:

> **illustrated**

Explanation:

*My prefix is evil.*

> **ill** is a synonym for evil

*My infix is an abbreviation.*

> **UST** is an abbreviation for the [United States Treasury](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/ust.asp),

*My suffix is in past tense.*

> **rated** is in its past tense form

*Together, they have no intersection.*

> All the affixes put together with no intersection yields **illustrated**.

Comment: Nice answer, but not what I intended. Subtle Hint: rot13("V" nz va cerfrag grafr.)

Answer (score 4):

> Malevolent

My prefix is evil

> Mal <-- a prefix for "bad" or "evil"

My infix is an abbreviation

> Evo for evolution

My suffix is in past tense

> lent, as in the past tense of lend

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> Disparate

My prefix is evil.

> [**Dis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dis_(Divine_Comedy)) encompasses the sixth through ninth circles of hell so could be described as evil.

My infix is an abbreviation.

> **Par** is an abbreviation for paragraph

My suffix is in past tense.

> **Ate** is the past tense of eat

Together, they have no intersection.

> **Disparate** describes things so unlike that there is no basis for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You might be

> **CROWDED**

My prefix is evil.

> **CROW** - a raven, possibly synonymous with a crow (same genus) is depicted historically as an evil presence

My infix is an abbreviation.

> **D** - D can be the abbreviation for many things: Day, December, Decimal, etc.

My suffix is in past tense.

> **ED** - ED is often added to words to make them past tense
> (Yes, probably a stretch)

Together, they have no intersection.

> All parts are separate with no overlap - **CROW-D-ED**

Title

> Compact - Many things in a compact area would be **CROWDED**.
> Also, if a compact car was very crowded, it may not make it to the next intersection.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be

> **illuminate**

Explanation:

*My prefix is evil.*

> **ill** is a synonym for evil

*My infix is an abbreviation.*

> **UMIN** is an abbreviation for the [University Medical Information Network](https://www.umin.ac.jp/english/whatisumin.htm)

*My suffix is in past tense.*

> **ate** is the past tense form of eat

*Together, they have no intersection.*

> All the affixes put together with no intersection yields **illuminate**.